# Angular 8 - add <script> that points to a javascript belonging to another website

Tags: javascript, angular

I am currently using angular 8 and its cli to develop my website.

**Problem:** I want to add `<script>` tag that points to another website's javascript file, e.g  `<script src="https://www.wiris.net/demo/plugins/app/WIRISplugins.js?viewer=image"></script>`

Beside adding to index.html, is there any other straightfoward way for us to do that inside a component. I don't expect the js from other website to be bundled together with my angular-based website during build. It should only be loaded dynamically when my application is running.

**Updated on 27 Jan 2020**

Below is the answer to my query.
Thanks to **Dean Van Greunen** for leading me to the below final implementation.

Below is how i dynamically reload the script element inside an angular component

```
 reloadScript(url:string){
      if(document.querySelector("#wiris"))
              document.querySelector("#wiris").remove()

      var wirisScriptEle = document.createElement('script');
      wirisScriptEle.id="wiris"
      wirisScriptEle.src = url;
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(wirisScriptEle);

  }
```

where the url is the "https://www.wiris.net/demo/plugins/app/WIRISplugins.js?viewer=image" to be passed in by the caller

**-----Further Query----------**
If anyone knows how to achieve the same thing without having to write the above javascript code such as directly put  into the html template without angular removing it away, do let me know. I will also accept that as an answer.

Comment: just add it to the index.html in our build folder

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yup, But as stated above, I wonder if there is other way, beside index.html.

Comment: please see my Answer. I hope it helps, that is the dynamic why you can add it to your project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

adding it to index doesn't bind it to the build, what you could do, is inside your root component you could do [this](https://codepen.io/deanvangreunen/pen/RwNddYd)

**Original:**

```
// Dynamic Load JS
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.onload = function() {
  console.log("Script loaded and ready");
};
script.src = "https://www.wiris.net/demo/plugins/app/WIRISplugins.js?viewer=image";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

**Updated Version:**

```
// Dynamic Load JS
let script_url = "https://www.wiris.net/demo/plugins/app/WIRISplugins.js?viewer=image";
let script_exist = false;
let headLen = document.getElementsByTagName('head').length;
let script_index = null;

// Search if script already exists
for(var i=0;i<headLen; i++){
  if(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[i].src==script_url){
    script_exist = true;
    script_index = i;
    break;
  }
}

//add script function (so i dont have duplicated code)
function addScript(){
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.onload = function() {
    console.log("Script loaded and ready");
  };
  script.src = script_url;
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}

// this will either add the script or remove the old one then add the new one, only 1 script will exist in the pages lifetime
if(!script_exist){
  addScript();
} else {
  if(script_index != null){
    document.getElementsByTagName('head').removeChild(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[script_index]);
  }
  addScript();
}
```

this updated version will check if the script exists, if so it will remove it then add it again.

Comment: Fantastic! This reply has helped me solve a problem that has haunted me for days.
Let me first explain what this script called WIRISplugins.js is doing. By loading this script, it will actually look for a special kind of xml tag that look something like this <math><msqrt><mn>111</mn></msqrt></math> , as an example, and turn it into an image showing a mathematics equation symbol.

Comment: This math tag is added dynamically to the html, whenever a button is clicked. But strangely, it does not turn into an image depsite me try load the WIRISplugins script in different ways. Then I realize i have to trigger your aforementioned group of codes to dyamically load the script whenever the button is clicked, cos I suspect the WIRISplugins.js seems to only recognize the math tag that is currently on the page, not tthose that are added later to the page.

Comment: However, your solution has one minor drawback. Whenever the button is clicked, your provided aforementioned code is triggered, it will dynamically add the <script src=""/> to the DOM.  Click 10 times, there will be 10 same <script src=""/>. appearing in the DOM. Not a big issue, now me trying to see how to avoid this.

Comment: @Bruce could you please check the updated code, it needs to be tested, it should work. thanks.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the updated code. Think there is a minor typo.
 document.getElementsByTagName('head').removeChild(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[script_index]);   //my IDE indicates that "Property 'removeChild' does not exist, cos the getElementsByTagName return a collection, not a specific element.

Comment: Nevertheless your code gives me some aspiration, and in the end, I implement my own version. I will update my question above to indicate the version I implements. Thanks again for your reply!

Comment: the collection has removeChild functions see https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_removechild.asp

Comment: I refer to your link, but still could not see anything about collection having removeChild functions. If u are referring to the example, var list = document.getElementById("myList");  list.removeChild(..);,  that list variable is a bit misleading,as it is not really a collection, it is still a single element, since getElementById always return a single element.

Do correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: every DOM Element, can have children. therefore every DOM Element has a RemoveChild Function, it may be a single object yes, but it has children, making it a so called "list"

Comment: I see what u mean. The reason why i highlight this, is because my IDE flagout error upon document.getElementsByTagName('head').removeChild(...), and indicates that HTML collection does not have removeChild(..).   But if i do this  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].removeChild(...),  then no error flags out

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add it inside the head tag of the Index.html file.

```
<head>
<script src="https://www.wiris.net/demo/plugins/app/WIRISplugins.js?viewer=image"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yup, But as stated above, I wonder if there is other way, beside index.html.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood , if you separate template file , from .ts file of the component , angular will try to add the related script file ( out put of ng build ) to the using template file ( .html ) , by using the same way you want to try (  )

In vueJs , this way called ( import external libraries using script tag ) , import plugins.

For angular , you can try to add the selected library to the top of the template , then try to access the function , using window.onload or document.onload() , or maybe it's better to get those beautiful functions , when component is in initial state ( implement OnInit , then add ngOnInit() {} )

use console.log() , when you have found the correct way to access the functions , make sure , you made global const object for the related component.

I hope this was useful.

Comment: But how do u add the js library ( which belong to another website),  to the top of the HTML template?

Comment: I have tried to to add it like this
```
<script src="./example.js"> </script>
```

to the top of the template file , couldn't (didn't have time to try more), find a way to access functions inside the example.js file.

I could access the function on this try 
```
<script src="./example.js"> </script>

<script>
hello()
</script>
```

but didn't go more

Comment: But if u add the 3 backticks  to the html template, won't the backticks be displayed on the page?

Comment: those backticks , are just used to separate code from comments. In template , just use script tag